# Mean Abs Error - create group to sum over before taking absolute value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, regression, metrics

this is a tricky one for me. I want to calculate the mean absolute error, but I want to add up several lines before taking the absolute value.

I feel like I have all the needed tools in front of me, but I am not combining them in the right way.

I have the following prediction result data frame:

| Group (not existing) | flight_date_exact_utc | scheduled_arrival_date/time_utc | tail_number | ond_flown | fuel_prediction_dev | fuel_prediction_abs_dev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 08.06.2021 | 09.06.2021 08:30 | Aircraft 1 | JFK-YYZ | 2600 | 2600 |
| 1 | 09.06.2021 | 09.06.2021 13:35 | Aircraft 1 | YYZ-ORD | -2500 | 2500 |
| 1 | 09.06.2021 | 09.06.2021 19:10 | Aircraft 1 | ORD-YYZ | -3100 | 3100 |
| 1 | 09.06.2021 | 10.06.2021 08:30 | Aircraft 1 | YYZ-JFK | 2300 | 2300 |
| 2 | 12.06.2021 | 13.06.2021 08:30 | Aircraft 1 | JFK-YYZ | -1200 | 1200 |
| 2 | 13.06.2021 | 14.06.2021 08:30 | Aircraft 1 | YYZ-JFK | 500 | 500 |
| 3 | 20.07.2021 | 21.07.2021 08:30 | Aircraft 2 | JFK-YYZ | 500 | 500 |
| 3 | 21.07.2021 | 21.07.2021 13:30 | Aircraft 2 | YYZ-ORD | -2300 | 2300 |
| 3 | 21.07.2021 | 21.07.2021 18:55 | Aircraft 2 | ORD-YYZ | -3700 | 3700 |
| 3 | 21.07.2021 | 22.07.2021 08:30 | Aircraft 2 | YYZ-JFK | 500 | 500 |
| 4 | 23.07.2021 | 23.07.2021 18:55 | Aircraft 2 | JFK-MIA | 500 | 500 |
| 4 | 23.07.2021 | 24.07.2021 08:30 | Aircraft 2 | MIA-JFK | -700 | 700 |
| 5 | 20.07.2021 | 21.07.2021 08:30 | Aircraft 2 | JFK-YYZ | 500 | 500 |
| 5 | 24.07.2021 | 21.07.2021 13:30 | Aircraft 2 | YYZ-ORD | -2300 | 2300 |
| 5 | 24.07.2021 | 21.07.2021 18:55 | Aircraft 2 | ORD-YYZ | -3700 | 3700 |
| 5 | This line is | missing, but | would be | YYZ-JFK | but I don't have | that info |

My aim is to get the MAE per group, i.e. the MAE for group 1 should be

`abs(2600-2500-3100+2300)/4 = 175`

instead of

`abs(2600)+abs(-2500)+abs(-3100)+abs(2300)/4 = 2625`

Problems:

- I don't have the group column, so I can't use groupby() on it.
- I can't group  by flight date as it is not always the same for one group
- Some lines are missing

Maybe helping:

- The grouping always starts when `left(ond_flown) == JFK` and ends with `right(ond_flown) == JFK`. But either or both lines might be missing (not often the case but still)
- the grouping does never comprise more than four lines, but often less.
- one group is always a concatenated flight chain of one `tail_number`

Thanks!